# Why is my ActionBar gone when typing on my input field?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Why is the blue portion at the top gone when editing my input field? (Images included)? How can I solve this?

The layout as it should be: [image]
The layout (as it should NOT be) when typing: [image]
The layout (as it should NOT be) after i typed: [image]

The XML code is as follows:
under here:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="nl.bosschert.john.rebornsportschallengegui.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

<TextView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editTextRondes"
android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editTextRondes"
android:layout_alignTop="@+id/editTextRondes"
android:layout_marginTop="-80dp"
android:text="Hoeveel rondes heb je gemaakt?"
android:textAlignment="center"
android:textColor="@color/header"
android:textSize="@dimen/header"
android:textStyle="bold" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextRondes"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/editTextRondes"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
    android:hint="Aantal rondes"
    android:textColor="@color/header"
    android:textColorHint="@color/colorRondesHint" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Try with linear-layout to avoid relativeness with each other as UI is not so complex.

Answer (score 1):

Your layout seems to be fine except this line `android:layout_below="@id/editTextRondes"`  which is not proper, 
perhaps there is some other code that might be causing this issue.

Comment: Did that, does not solve my problem, but I think it solves a lot of upcoming problems :)

Answer (score 0):

Your are incorrect and unnecessary attributes, try this :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="nl.bosschert.john.rebornsportschallengegui.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Hoeveel rondes heb je gemaakt?"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/header"
        android:textSize="@dimen/header"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextRondes"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/editTextRondes"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"      
        android:hint="Aantal rondes"
        android:textColor="@color/header"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorRondesHint" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:
modify `manifest.xml` :

```
<activity
        android:name=".xxxActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"/>
```

or:
add `<ScrollView>` to your RelativeLayout.

```
<ScrollView>
   <RelativeLayout>
    ...
   </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: This did work on my Galaxy S7, however not on my Galaxy S4 & Galaxy S5... When I delete the code you suggest, the problem only exists on my Galaxy S7 and is gone on my Galaxy S5 and S4. I think it is my phone that is causing the problem somehow. Maybe it has something to do with my custom screen size setting (HD / FHD / WQHD) which i can choose on android 7)

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided by kingfeng solved my problem on my Samsung Galaxy S7, however created the problem on my Samsung Galaxy S5 and Samsung Galaxy S4.

> try this: modify AndroidManifest.xml

This did work on my Galaxy S7, however not on my Galaxy S4 & Galaxy S5... When I delete the code kingfeng suggests, the problem only exists on my Galaxy S7 and is gone on my Galaxy S5 and S4. I think it is my phone that is causing the problem somehow. Maybe it has something to do with my custom screen size setting (HD / FHD / WQHD) which i can choose on android 7)

Anyway, i decided to delete the ActionBar, since I do not necessary need it.